# closest numeric value in database using Prisma Client

Tags: sql, sqlite, prisma, prisma-graphql

Is there any way I could re-write this SQL query using **Prisma Client**.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [myTable] 
WHERE Name = 'Test' and Size = 2 and PType = 'p'
ORDER BY ABS( Area - @input )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [queryRaw](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access) and directly pass the raw SQL to execute it.

It would look like this:

```
const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [myTable] 
WHERE Name = 'Test' and Size = 2 and PType = 'p'
ORDER BY ABS( Area - @input )`
```